# Does the following result hold in the full Solovay model (2)

Tags: set-theory

This is a sequel to my previous question with the same title. Let $N:=M[G]$ be the full Solovay model. And let $R$ be an archimedean complete real closed field in $M[G]$ (so $R$ has cardinality $2^{\aleph_0}$ in $M[G]$). Let $X$ be a subset of $R$ (or of $R \times R$) which is definable from a countable sequence of ordinals and $R$ (so $R$ is a parameter in the formula defining $X$).

Does is it hold that $X$ has the Baire property in $M[G]$?

Edit: In my case, $R \subset HOD$ and $R \subset K \in HOD$ where $K$ is an algebraically closed field, and the field structure on $R$ is induced by that of $K$. Does the result hold in this case?

Comment: We can assume without loss of generality that the underlying set of $R$ is $\omega^\omega$. Is the field structure of $R$ ordinal definable?

Comment: That is blatantly false.

Comment: Ah really? Why?

Comment: Err, no, you're right. I was thinking about ordinal definable from a sequence of real numbers.

Comment: I must be missing something. Your $R$ is the field of reals in $N$, up to isomorphism. Isn’t one of the main properties of the Solovay model that *every* set of reals has the property of Baire, definable or not?

Comment: $N$ is the full Solovay model not the usual one in which every set of reals is Baire measurable.

Comment: @Emil: If the field structure is itself ordinal definable with real parameters, then yes. But it's not necessarily the case.

Comment: Oh. If the full Solovay model is what is called $M[G]$ on the Wikipedia page, it is a model of ZFC. Then, for every $X\subseteq\mathbb R$, you can find an isomorphic copy $R$ of $\mathbb R$ where the image of $X$ *is* an ordinal (and therefore ordinal definable), so you are in effect asking whether every subset of $\mathbb R$ has the property of Baire, which it has not, due to choice again.

Comment: @Emil: why you can find an isomorphic copy of $X$ which is ordinal definable? How can the isomoprhic image of a subset of reals be an ordinal in general? Recall that $R$ is a real closed field.

Comment: By choice, there is a bijection of $X$ with an ordinal (or even a cardinal). Extend it to a bijection of $\mathbb R$ with something, call that something $R$, and lift the field structure (hence order and topology) from $\mathbb R$ to $R$ along the bijection.

Comment: Yes but in this case the field structure is not definable, no?

Comment: Nothing in your question demands $R$ or its field structure to be definable.

Comment: See my edit please.

Comment: Note that $\Bbb C$ has *many* subfields isomorphic to $\Bbb R$, each which can be endowed with an order via such isomorphism.

Comment: @AsafKaragila: That’s a good point. And in fact, if we take for $R$ *any* of these subfields such that $[\mathbb C:R]=2$ (save $\mathbb R$ itself), and for $X$ the intersection of $R$ with the (Euclidean) unit disk in $\mathbb C$, then $X$ is obviously definable from $R$, but it does not have the property of Baire in $R$ (otherwise the isomorphism of $R$ to $\mathbb R$, and thus its extension to an automorphism of $\mathbb C$, would be continuous using a form of Pettis theorem).